# Solving $n(4n+3)=2^m-1$ in positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, quadratic-integer-rings, exponential-diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$n(4n+3)=2^m-1\,.$$

This is an interesting equation which was sent to me by a friend (probably found online). I have been scratching my head about whether or not this has a unique solution in positive integers which I have found to be $(n,m)=(1,3)$. My first approach was trying to work some mod casework but it hasn't been really helpful and the only thing I found which I guess was worth, is that $$n \equiv 1\pmod{ 8},\forall \ m \geq 3\,.$$ I have noticed that $2^m-1$ for $m=3$ is prime and so I conjecture that whenever $2^m-1$ is not a prime then the equation will not have a solution in positive integers but I am stuck on proving this last statement. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: You can write $$p^2+7=2^{m+4}\,,$$ where $p:=8n+3$.    You may need to work in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$.  Fortunately, this is a unique factorization domain.

Comment: @Batominovski I'm sorry but I'm not really familiar with the last notation you are using. Can you tell me what to search to find out about it?

Comment: If you got this problem from a pre-college math contest resource, then I think you can safely ignore what I said.  There are perhaps better solutions without dealing with quadratic integers.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer if you are curious.)

Comment: Although @Batominovsky suggested a wonderful quick solution using algebraic number theory, specifically, the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-7}]}$ is a $\mathrm{UFD}$, for an elementary solution consider the $2$ cases, $$(1)\quad\gcd(n,4n+3)=1\\(2)\quad\gcd(n,4n+3)=3$$ in both cases assume $m$ to be composite and then factorise to get contradiction. You may also need Fermat's little theorem for prime factors of $n$ and $4n+3$. Go ahead.

Comment: You may need the following well-known factorisation identity, $$2^{ab}-1=(2^a-1)(2^{a(b-1)}+2^{a(b-2)}+\cdots+2^a+1)$$ for natural numbers $a,b$.

Comment: Back to my first comment, all nonnegative integer solutions $(p,q)$ to $p^2+7=2^{q}$  are $(1,3)$, $(3,4)$, $(6,5)$, $(11,7)$, and $(181,15)$.  However, there may indeed be a different way to tackle this problem.  (EDIT: Just saw that somebody already posted an answer with the same idea.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation  in disguise, then

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya For the elementary solution why is it safe to assume that $m$ is composite? $2^m-1$ can be composite even if $m$ is prime, e.g. $m=11$. How can I continue on if $m$ is prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as a quadratic equation in $n$: $4n^2+3n -2^m+1 = 0\implies \triangle = 3^2-4(4)(1-2^m)= 9-16+16\cdot 2^m=2^{m+4}-7=k^2\implies k^2+7=2^{m+4} $. This problem has appeared in an article by author J.Cremona of Nottingham UK, and in that article, they proved that the only possible solutions are: $m + 4 = 3,4,5,7,15$. I leave this for you to finish.

**Reference:**

$1)$.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266524000_On_the_Diophantine_equation_x_2_7y_m

Comment: Hmm, if $m+4=3$ then $m=-1$ and $2^m-1$ is fractional. How can this be a solution for integer $n$?

Comment: I said the words " possible ". Did you read it carefully ? The whole point is the show that attached article with the main result. The "little" details are for the OP to sort out. I am not in the position or obligated to "provide" the full solution. This is just a contribution which shows the main ideas. So keep that in mind.